# Bluetooth version and capabilities of a USB adapter

Tags: windows, bluetooth

Is there a Windows utility that shows detailed information about the current bluetooth device attached to the PC? Like supported bluetooth versions, standards, etc.

Answer (score 4):

USBview gives all the relevant info for USB printers that I've had to deal with, it would be my first thing to try for the bluetooth adaptor:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities/usbview.zip

Note that I've had my copy for ages, I don't remember from where. The link above was from googling just now, I cannot verify its contents.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems it only gives generic USB info about the device. I need more Bluetooth specific info. Btw, this utility comes with "Debugging Tools for Windows".