# How to check the Bluetooth capabilities and version?

Tags: windows-10, usb, bluetooth

I am starting to work/fiddle with Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE (BLE, Low Energy). I want to use Bluetooth for communication between Windows 10, Android and ESP32.

I bought Bluetooth cards and USB adapters for my Windows 10 PC but they seem to work only in part and the manufactures descriptions are very limited.

**I am looking for Windows software which shows the capabilities of Bluetooth devices (i.e. PCE-Card, USB-Adapter, etc.). I want to know which Bluetooth version is supported and maybe other Bluetooth details.**

I checked for similar questions and I found i.e. this question:
[Bluetooth version and capabilities of a USB adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/321554/bluetooth-version-and-capabilities-of-a-usb-adapter)
The suggested tool in the answer shows nothing on my PC and the question and answers are years old.

I installed the ASUS PCE-AC55BT card in my PC which has WLAN and Bluetooth. The description only shows: "Bluetooth 4.0 and BLE" and no more details.

I also tested a no-name USB adapter which is supposed to support BLE but it seems it doesn't support it. That's what some software tells me. But I don't know if the software just does not recognize the Bluetooth device or driver or the Bluetooth device does not work correctly and maybe it needs other or additional drivers.

I found already one USB adapter with lots of functionality and I ordered it already. But that will take time before it arrives and likely it won't show me the capabilities of other Bluetooth adapters.
https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-Tools/Development-Kits/nRF52840-Dongle/GetStarted

Comment: The Basic Bluetooth features can be known by its HCI and LMP versions. The only few very specific can't be read as simple but those, usualy, do not matter.

Answer (score 1):

First, to determine if your Windows computer is compliant with Bluetooth Low Energy:

1. Ensure Bluetooth is enabled
2. Run the Device Manager
3. Open the "Bluetooth" branch on the left, which will expand to show all
   Bluetooth drivers
4. If there is a driver named "Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator", then your
   computer supports Bluetooth Low Energy.

Second, to scan your network for compatible BLE devices needs a third-party tool.
Here are some that I found (but didn't test):

- [Bluetooth LE Lab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-le-lab/9n6jd37gwzc8?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  (Microsoft Store)
- [Bluetooth LE Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-le-explorer/9n0ztkf1qd98?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  (Microsoft Store)
- [BLEConsole](https://sensboston.github.io/BLEConsole/)
- [BleScanner](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/blescanner/9nblggh4w7g4?activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
  (Microsoft Store but without much documentation)

Comment: Thanks. I just checked on my PCs. On the PC with the ASUS card it shows the Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator. On the notebook with the cheap USB Bluetooth adapter, which is supposed to be version 4.0 it does not show Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator. I tried already some of those programs. I think looking at the device manager like you suggested is the better idea. The programs just show "nothing" for BLE on my notebook.

Comment: Today I tested in several shops USB Bluetooth adapters which all claimed to support Bluetooth 4.0. I let Windows 10 automatically install the drivers. Only one device installed the LTE drivers (see above). It's from Vention (first time I heard that name). What I found surprising is that they all had the same chip, the CSR8510.